# What's difference between a[href^="#"] and a[href*=\\#]

Tags: javascript, dom, css-selectors

What's the difference between

```
'a[href^="#"]'
```

and

```
'a[href*=\\#]'
```

I would like to create a smooth scroll javascript that affects all internal links on the website.

This's the full script.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $('a[href^="#"]').bind('click.smoothscroll',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    var target = this.hash,
        $target = $(target);

    $('html, body').stop().animate( {
      'scrollTop': $target.offset().top-40
    }, 900, 'swing', function () {
      window.location.hash = target;
    } );
  } );
} );
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: Excuse me, That's not have any information that l ask for.

Comment: `^=` looks for an attribute value that *starts with* the given string. `*=` looks for an attribute that *contains* the given string.

Comment: From that page: "`[attr^=value]` Represents elements with an attribute name of attr whose value is prefixed (preceded) by value." and later, "`[attr*=value]` Represents elements with an attribute name of attr whose value contains at least one occurrence of value within the string."

Comment: I think OP asked for `\\#` (which i believe is css `\#`) and `#`

Comment: Yes that correct,

Comment: We need more context regarding what this code is used for. Strings containing what appear to be CSS selectors are somewhat meaningless out of context. How are these strings being used?

Comment: @appleapple it's still the same.  backslash is just a character escape

Comment: @user120242 yes I know. (tbh I'm not sure attribute value should be escaped or not.)

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the code in context.

Comment: @user120242 I just overlooked the `^` & `*` and think OP asked for `\\#` & `#`

Comment: Thank you for your respond, l already add code into the post.

Comment: your internal links have to have a css selector after #.  That's how it finds elements to scroll to.  There's no there way to do it, because you need some identifier for the element you want to focus on.  If you want it ot work for "everything", you'll have to write a function to scan elements for an identifier you will use for focusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `^=` is the "attribute starts with" CSS selector
- `*=` is the "attribute contains" CSS selector

You need `\\` to escape in two contexts:

- `a[href*=#]` is not a valid CSS selector; needs to be `a[href*=\#]` or `a[href*="#"]`
- `\` needs to be escaped with itself in JavaScript string literals

```js
let a = 'a[href^="#"]';
let b = 'a[href*=\\#]';
let c = 'a[href*="#"]';
let d = 'a[href*=#]';
console.log(a, document.querySelectorAll(a).length);
console.log(b, document.querySelectorAll(b).length);
console.log(c, document.querySelectorAll(c).length);
try {
  document.querySelectorAll(d);
} catch(err) {
  console.log(err.message);
}
```

```html
<a href="#foo">Blah</a>
<a href="foo#bar">Blah</a>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, You save me,
l have tested a[href*=\\#] it works fine.

Comment: I've added a clarification into my answer. Backslash is not the only way, you can just quote as in the first selector.

Comment: Excuse me, I don't speak English that well and I'm a newbie for Javascript, Could you please rewrite my code for the best selector, that will save me a lot of time, thank you.